# How do i update a list using the for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

Rather than join using the "+" operator and remove duplicates afterwards, I'd like to update items in a list using the for loop as per the code below:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
x = 0

for lines in fh:
    words = lines.split()
    lst = words[:]
    if lst[x] in lst:
        continue
    y = lst[x]
    lst_full =lst.append("y")
print(list_full)
```

in the file, there are 4 lists in total, i would like the code to automatically update list one with the items in the other lists. Please help.

Comment: Hi, can u send us the lists?

Comment: use the feature of `python-set` and `set-typecasting`, also `lst.append()` does not return anything so `lst_full` is a `None type object`. One more thing if you have an empty file, that means loop will not be initiated so your last `print` statement will throw `declaration error`, saying `no object named 'list_full' exists`

Comment: You have several anomalies in your code, did you even run it on your system before asking, because i see several exceptions raising, try debugging your code and you'll find what anomalies I am talking about, you are appending "y" which is a string and y is a variable which will not going to be appended to your list.

Comment: Hi Yashasvi, the file is not empty as I have tried successfully to add the lists normally using the loop function. My aim here is to automatically avoid duplicates particularly with the append method.

Comment: Hi Yashasvi, i believe the append method follows the format a.append("x") if x is string. In this instance as well, all the items are of the string type. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: But that is not a good practice, in industry your code will be evaluated on each kind of test cases, those test cases even include empty files as well, at that time the officials will not take the reason that your list will never be empty.

Answer (score 1):

if you have 2 lists `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `x = [5, 6, 7, 8]`, now if you do `a.append("x")`, what you might be thinking that resultant output will be `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, but this will not be the case, since `"x"` is a string and `x` is a variable so resultant output will be `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, "x"]`, also even if you use `a.append(x)`, the resultant output will be `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7, 8]]`, for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, you need to use
`a += x`. Hope that helps and cleared all your doubts. And to remove duplicates, do this
`a = list(set(a))`

Comment: Yashasvi, thanks for your input. But i expect the code to query the list one character at a time which should mitigate your concern. Also, thats why I have used the "if" statement to do a conditional filter. But thanks a lot. For now, the error i get is "bad input on line 10, the line with "continue".